# Is json_token better/safer/faster then a session? What means tampered, thus unusable?

Tags: php, session, json-web-token

I have found the following article and code

https://coderwall.com/p/8wrxfw/goodbye-php-sessions-hello-json-web-tokens

https://github.com/rmcdaniel/angular-codeigniter-seed/blob/master/api/application/helpers/jwt_helper.php

What means the words `If the token has been tampered with then $token will be empty there will not be an id available. The JWT class makes sure that invalid data is never made available. If the token is tampered with, it will be unusable.` . ? Is there some technology, that if smbd else reads the token, it becomes changed ???

Is it better to use a token, versus session?

Have realised, that

(1) if server send some key in hidden field,

which is changed by owner javascript in time, and in case of ajax call, redirection or posting using some rule depending on time signature present in the key and other paramters like counter,

(2) then server does not expects the key to be the same,

but approx can gues the value by time signatures and some other defined parameters,

(3) thus if it gets the same key, it means hacker is sending the key:

Jwt token is a token, which power is that it is not possible to change it, any changes destroy the token.

But hackers usually does not change keys, they try to identify them and send the same .  Thus the secure key is the key which changes in time.

Gogin to implement one and write some article.

Do you know smth about this type of security ?

Comment: https://medium.com/myplanet-musings/what-is-a-json-web-token-2193f383e963 - this explains many purposes, but i stil does not understnad what means ` if you tamper it will be empty ` and how this is achieved ?

Comment: Is it possible to make kind of javascript, what detects if some other javascript reads the data, thus destoys the token  in the  hidden field ?

Comment: seems i have to use the beforeunload and unload events , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Answer (score 0):

It means that the token, which has been encoded with a secret key held on the server side, cannot be decoded with the same key if it has been altered in any way. Thus any decoding attempt will return a empty value instead of an invalid token.

This of course requires that the secret key stays secret (if it doesn't then there are bigger problems in hand, I would say).

Comment: but usually nobody changes the keys, usually they are read by some means, and sen back unchanged.  The change of the key is not a problem of security. I changed a bit the post, i realised that secure keys are the keys which changes in time :)